# Print the output in spool , and use the same output in different varaibles

Tags: shell, unix

Below i am trying to print the output which is stored in `input.lst`

- `a.poid_id0` should be stored in one variable
- `a.Account_obj_id0` should be stored in another variable
- `b.BILL_INFO_ID` should be stored in another variable
- `b.PAYINFO_OBJ_ID0` should be stored in another variable
- `b.poid_id0` should be stored in another variable.

I need to use these above variables in while loop.

```
SPOOL input.lst
sqlplus -s ${DB_STRING} << EOF

select a.poid_id0,a.Account_obj_id0, b.BILL_INFO_ID,b.PAYINFO_OBJ_ID0,b.poid_id0
from ACCT_IBAN_ASSOCIATION_T a, billinfo_t b
where a.ACCOUNT_OBJ_ID0 = b.ACCOUNT_OBJ_ID0
and b.BILL_INFO_ID !='Account Bill';

SPOOL OFF
EOF
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below
col1, col2, col3 etc should be your variables :

```
output=$(sqlplus -S ${DB_STRING} << EOF

select a.poid_id0,a.Account_obj_id0, b.BILL_INFO_ID,b.PAYINFO_OBJ_ID0,b.poid_id0
from ACCT_IBAN_ASSOCIATION_T a, billinfo_t b
where a.ACCOUNT_OBJ_ID0 = b.ACCOUNT_OBJ_ID0
and b.BILL_INFO_ID !='Account Bill';
SPOOL OFF
EOF
)
echo -e "$output" | while read col1 col2 col3 (etc..) ; do ... ; done
```